# Sorting files in bash

Tags: bash, file, sorting, terminal

I wiil appreciate your help.

I have files:

```
V0.1__file_a.sql
V0.2__file_b.sql
V0__file_c.sql
V1.1__file_a.sql
V1.2__b.sql
V1.3__c.sql
V1.4__d.sql
V1.5__e.sql
V1.6__f.sql
V1__file_g.sql
```

I would like to use **sort** command to sort them in next way

```
V0__file_c.sql
V0.1__file_a.sql
V0.2__file_b.sql
V1__file_g.sql
V1.1__file_a.sql
V1.2__b.sql
V1.3__c.sql
V1.4__d.sql
V1.5__e.sql
V1.6__f.sql
```

flags `-n`, `-g` do not help me with this.

And i seem to broke my brain solving this

Could someone to help with that?

Thanks!

Comment: On *what* is your sort algorithm based?

Comment: Or your file naming scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this dataset, only sort of the first field.

```
$: printf "%s\n" V0.1__file_a.sql V0.2__file_b.sql V0__file_c.sql | sort -t _ -k 1,1
V0__file_c.sql
V0.1__file_a.sql
V0.2__file_b.sql
```

Using `-k 1,2` fails for me also unless I use a dictionary sort with it (`-d`).

```
$: printf "%s\n" V0.1__file_a.sql V0.2__file_b.sql V0__file_c.sql | sort -t _ -k 1,2
V0.1__file_a.sql
V0.2__file_b.sql
V0__file_c.sql
```

but works with `-d`

```
$: printf "%s\n" V0.1__file_a.sql V0.2__file_b.sql V0__file_c.sql | sort -d -t _ -k 1,2
V0__file_c.sql
V0.1__file_a.sql
V0.2__file_b.sql
```

Dictionary sort will "consider only blanks and alphanumeric characters", so the dots and underscores are ignored, making all the filenames single strings of alphanumarics, and numbers *as* characters sort to the top.

`-d` alone still fails though - you *need* to establish fields.

```
$: printf "%s\n" V0.1__file_a.sql V0.2__file_b.sql V0__file_c.sql | sort -d
V0.1__file_a.sql
V0.2__file_b.sql
V0__file_c.sql
```

Using `-t _` sets underscore as the delimiter, but sort is ignoring it on my implementation as well if I don't explicitly tell it to *use* a key field.

The combination forces `V0` to be compared to `V01` and `V02` without comparing underscores to dots, so you get the order you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The `-k` option accepts a key definition parameter that you can use together with `-t _` to use the underscore as a field separator:

```
> sort -t _ -k 1,2 data.txt 
V0__file_c.sql
V0.1__file_a.sql
V0.2__file_b.sql
V1__file_g.sql
V1.1__file_a.sql
V1.2__b.sql
V1.3__c.sql
V1.4__d.sql
V1.5__e.sql
V1.6__f.sql
```

Comment: While it's true that -t _ does set a field delimiter, and -k the key definition, I can't reproduce your results on my macOS 11.4 machine neither with sort nor gsort, neither with `LC_COLLATE=C` or `en_US.UTF-8`. In all cases I've tried, `V1__file_g.sql` ends up on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

The following gives you the correct output

```
$ cat files.txt | sort -t'_' -k1,1
V0__file_c.sql
V0.1__file_a.sql
V0.2__file_b.sql
V1__file_g.sql
V1.1__file_a.sql
V1.2__b.sql
V1.3__c.sql
V1.4__d.sql
V1.5__e.sql
V1.6__f.sql
```